# My iOS App rejected due to declares support for location in the UIBackgroundModes key in your Info.plist

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, appstore-approval

I am using live tracking of employees and geofencing of multiple custom shapes region in my app thats why I needed background location updates but my app rejected by apple. Below are apple message:

Although we understand your concern regarding 2.5.4, your app still declares support for location in the UIBackgroundModes key in your Info.plist file but does not have any features that require persistent location.

To resolve this issue, please revise your app to include additional features for your users that require the persistent use of real-time location updates while the app is in the background.

Please help me regarding this

Comment: Does you app meta data adequately explain how you are using background location?  How about your background location usage string?

Comment: We have explain user when get location permission popup appears: "We use location feature to get the location of user when the user clocks into time clock feature".

Comment: Ok. To me, that would describe why you need “when in use” permission, not “always” permission. You have described the need for location at a specific point in time while I am using the app, not a need for continuous location monitoring.

Comment: Can you please let me know what can i do now?

Comment: You can either revise your usage description and meta data to adequately explain why you need the user's location at all times instead of just when they clock in or revise your app to only require "when in use" permissions.  Does your app automatically clock people out when they leave the location? Perhaps explain that.

Comment: We have started location updates when user clocked in. (clocked in means user started shifts). We need location to track user on live based and also we used geofencing feature to track if user goes outsite of his working area or come inside working area.

Comment: Then make sure that you explain that in your meta data.  You also need to ensure that this is explained in your usage string.  Something like "We use your location in the background while you are clocked in to determine if you leave the work area".  Your current usage description does not adequately explain to the user how and why they are being tracked.

Comment: What do you mean by explain in metadata?

Comment: The metadata is the information you enter in App Store Connect that is shown in the App Store.

Comment: Is it works? Apple give me this error: "We noticed that your app declares support for location in the UIBackgroundModes key in your Info.plist file but still does not have any features that require persistent location. Specifically, your app uses location background mode for the sole purpose of tracking employees, which is not appropriate on the App Store".

Comment: Right, so there is your answer.  Apple will not accept your app in its current state due to privacy concerns.  You will need to limit yourself to when in use location tracking.  I must admit that when you described your use case, that I would be uneasy about installing this app.  If you do want to proceed with this functionality you will probably need to develop this app under the enterprise program, not as an App Store app

Comment: Thanks for update. Can you please let me know how to develop under enterprise program.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/programs/enterprise/